# ORA-39014 import in Oracle 19c from DMP file of Oracle12c

Tags: oracle, import, impdp, oracle-19c, expdp

I have been testing out expdp/impdp of databases from 12c to 19c( newly created database) but one db have game me this error:

`nohup impdp system/****@CKLPROD CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY PARALLEL=4 DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=EXP_CKLPROD_20210317_B419C.DMP LOGFILE=IMP_CKLPROD_20210317_B419C_META.log > IMP_CKLPROD_20210317_B419C_META.out &`

```
> Processing object type
> DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/PROCEDURE/ALTER_PROCEDURE ORA-39014: One or
> more workers have prematurely exited. ORA-39029: worker 1 with process
> name "DW00" prematurely terminated ORA-39014: One or more workers have
> prematurely exited. ORA-39029: worker 2 with process name "DW00"
> prematurely terminated Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_02" stopped due
> to fatal error at Wed Mar 17 14:04:14 2021 elapsed 0 00:18:42
```

the alert log have the following ORA errors:

```
Line 122: ORA-00800: soft external error, arguments: [Set Priority Failed], [VKTM], [Check traces and OS configuration], [Check Oracle document and MOS notes], []
Line 355: ORA-00800: soft external error, arguments: [Set Priority Failed], [VKTM], [Check traces and OS configuration], [Check Oracle document and MOS notes], []
Line 508: ORA-1109 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE CLOSE NORMAL...
Line 639: ORA-00800: soft external error, arguments: [Set Priority Failed], [VKTM], [Check traces and OS configuration], [Check Oracle document and MOS notes], []
Line 781: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 1 of thread 1
Line 784: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 1 of thread 1
Line 788: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 2 of thread 1
Line 791: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 2 of thread 1
Line 795: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 3 of thread 1
Line 798: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 3 of thread 1
Line 803: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 1 of thread 1
Line 806: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 1 of thread 1
Line 810: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 2 of thread 1
Line 813: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 2 of thread 1
Line 817: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 3 of thread 1
Line 820: ORA-00313: open failed for members of log group 3 of thread 1
Line 2208: ORA-00800: soft external error, arguments: [Set Priority Failed], [VKTM], [Check traces and OS configuration], [Check Oracle document and MOS notes], []
Line 3062: ORA-00800: soft external error, arguments: [Set Priority Failed], [VKTM], [Check traces and OS configuration], [Check Oracle document and MOS notes], []
Line 3900: ORA-00800: soft external error, arguments: [Set Priority Failed], [VKTM], [Check traces and OS configuration], [Check Oracle document and MOS notes], []
Line 4733: ORA-00800: soft external error, arguments: [Set Priority Failed], [VKTM], [Check traces and OS configuration], [Check Oracle document and MOS notes], []
Line 5055: ORA-00800: soft external error, arguments: [Set Priority Failed], [VKTM], [Check traces and OS configuration], [Check Oracle document and MOS notes], []
Line 5834: ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [ph2csql_idndef_to_diana()+39] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0x0] [PC:0x55CDCD7] [SI_KERNEL(general_protection)] []
Line 5853: ORA-07445: exception encountered: core dump [ph2csql_idndef_to_diana()+39] [SIGSEGV] [ADDR:0x0] [PC:0x55CDCD7] [SI_KERNEL(general_protection)] []
```

Comment: You will need to contact Oracle Support to resolve this.

Comment: What operating system are you running on? What Edition of Oracle are you using (Standard / Enterprise)? Some ORA-xxxxx errors can be looked up on the Oracle Support site. However, this requires you to register with Oracle.E.g. [Doc ID 2551359.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2551359.1).

Comment: Do the timestamps of the error messages coincide with the run of the `IMPDP` command? It looks like the Oracle instance is having issues while starting the database, which doesn't normally happen when you just import a dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your Oracle instance is failing you. But let's roll it up from the beginning.

## IMPDP in Parallel

To execute the `IMPDP` command with the `PARALLEL` parameter you have to meet the following requirements:

> - This parameter is valid only in the **Enterprise Edition** **<sup>(check)</sup>** of Oracle Database 11g or later.
> - To import a table or table partition in parallel (using PQ slaves), you must have the `DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE` **<sup>(check)</sup>** role.
> - Transportable tablespace metadata cannot be imported in parallel.
> - Metadata cannot be imported in parallel when the NETWORK_LINK parameter is also used
> - The following ojbects cannot be imported in parallel:
>
>   - TRIGGER
>   - VIEW
>   - OBJECT_GRANT
>   - SEQUENCE
>   - CONSTRAINT
>   - REF_CONSTRAINT.

<sup>***Reference:** [3. Data Pump Import | PARALLEL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-3081A258-0C23-40B0-8487-9C7A0D248E23) (Oracle Help Center)*</sup>

## ORA-xxxxx Errors

> **Disclaimer**
> Due to copyright restrictions I am only able to provide you with some general links to the Oracle Doc IDs which may or may not provide you with a solution to your issue(s). **Registration is required** to view this information in full.

#### ORA-00800 Errors

- [ORA-00800: soft external error, arguments: [Set Priority Failed], [VKTM], for Oracle Linux (Doc ID 2718971.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2718971.1) (Oracle on *nix systems)
- [ORA-00800: Soft External Error, Arguments: [Set Priority Failed], [VKTM] [Check traces and OS configuration] (Doc ID 2551359.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2551359.1) (Oracle on IBM AIX systems)

#### ORA-00313 Errors

- [ORA-00313 at Startup After a New Redo Log Member is Added (Doc ID 1005110.6)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1005110.6)

#### ORA-07445

- [ORA-7445 Troubleshooting Tool](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1521910.1) (Oracle Online Troubleshooting Tool)

This option requires you to upload an IPS package to Oracle in order for them to analyse the data. If you create an SR with Oracle and supply the error message ORA-7445 in the case, then you will be automatically redirected to this tool. There is however a downloadable version under that link.

## If All Else Fails

There do seem to be issues when trying to import 12c objects into 19c so you might want to contact a certified Oracle consultant or if you have a Support Identifier with Oracle open up a new Service Request.

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation regrading impdp. I actually did series of testing without parallel and FULL=Y, but still having the issue. I tried to export and import different database with same object/structures and I get the same error, which led me to believe that it has compatibility issues with 19c. Other databases from same server are fine. I'm gonna raise this one to Oracle support.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help the OP; it did help me for similar problem, where `PARALLEL` was causing the issue, and missing `DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE` role.  I had nothing in the alert or other logs in my case!